# android download manager dont dowload instantly its wait for a while or dont download my urls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-download-manager

I use android download manager to download my image url's but after calling them the download did not instantly begin and about 5 or 10 minutes later downloads starts. I don't know where did I wrong but pleased that s.o can help

my download code is :

```
String downloadUrlOfImage = instaList.get(position).getThumbnail_url();
            File direct =
                    new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "instadownloader" + "/");


            if (!direct.exists()) {
                direct.mkdir();
            }
            Log.i("Log1","type is: " + instaList.get(position).getTypename());

            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(downloadUrlOfImage);
            Log.i("Log1","download url is : " + downloadUri);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle(filename)
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                            File.separator + "instadownloader" + File.separator + filename);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Download is starting" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Did you try a different URL perhaps it's an issue from the server-end ?